# Optimal distance and power exponent in IDW

Tags: r, interpolation, spatial-statistics

I want to apply IDW interpolation for my region of interest, and through leave-one-out cross validation I want to find the optimal values for the distance parameter and the power exponent. I know that I can find the optimal distance, running IDW in a loop for many distances and each time for each distance to perform the cross validation. In this case I will have a scatterplot of distance (x-axis) and error (y-axis). The optimal distance value is the one that gives the lowest error. The same I can do for finding the optimal power exponent. 
What I want to do is, somehow, run IDW for different distances and different power exponents at once and each time the result of the cross-validation to be stored in a 3D scatterplot in which, in x-axis there will be distance, in y-axis there will be the power exponent and in z-axis there will be the error for each combination of distance and power.

How can I perform this in R?

Comment: Do you have a basic code to work with? i.e. the one which creates the IDW.. I would suggest also to:
1) Use ggplot2 to facet your plots, instead of a 3D one, which for my taste is hard to read.
It might be a long process to write the code, but can give better results from random values with visual inspection of results.
2) You might prefer to let your code to optimize your values, using a machine learning algorithm.